# chef resource block syntax

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I'm new to Chef and Ruby.

```
template '/var/www/html/index.html' do # ~FC033
  source 'index.html.erb'
  mode '0644'
  owner 'web_admin'
  group 'web_admin'
end
```

What is the syntax inside the block, for example, source 'index.html.erb', like a [space] b, is this syntax defined in Ruby or as a additional DSL part in Chef?

Answer (score 1):

It's a syntax for writing methods, in ruby you can omit parentheses. Whole chef is written in ruby and using ruby dsl

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Przemek's answer a bit, It's all Ruby but Chef applies a lot of special stuff to make the DSL look more declarative. If you add back all the optional-y things, it's maybe a bit clearer how this works (not an exact translation because of the block):

```
self.template('/var/www/html/index.html', do # ~FC033
  self.source('index.html.erb')
  ...
end)
```

`template()` is a method call that takes a resource name and a block which forms the resource body (blocks are a feature of ruby that allows easily passing an anonymous chuck of code to a method). As part of running that `template()` method, it creates a `Chef::Resource::Template` object instance, and then runs the provided block against it. `source()` is a method on that `Template` class which gets or sets the `@source` instance variable, in this case we're setting it.

Comment: what does the "self" mean?

Comment: In Ruby, that's a method that always returns a reference to the current object in whatever context you happen to be in. The first one is a reference to the `Chef::Recipe` object, the second to an instance of `Chef::Resource::Template`.